# Is there a way I can incorporate mailto links with ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, mailto

I create an Object and use ngFor to loop through it and create a table. I would like to somehow incorporate mailto links if possible.

I have this `finalResults` object that looks something like this:

```
[
{key: 'example@example.com', value: 'message'}
]
```

Where message is something like

```
"Please contact the Login Team for help."
```

I would like to make Login Team a mailto link.

I have already tried making the message like this

```
Please contact the <A HREF="mailto:name@mydomain.com">Login Team</A> for help.
```

But on the webpage it just displayed that exactly. There was no link.

I use `ngFor` to loop through my object and make a table.

```
< <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
          {{ col }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of finalResults">
        <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr></tr>
    </table>
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your text as html text then consider using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) binding:

**ts**

```
finalResults = [
  { 
     key: 'example@example.com',
     value: 'Please contact the <A HREF="mailto:name@mydomain.com">Login Team</A> for help.' 
  }
];
```

**html**

```
<td [innerHTML]="item.value"></td>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/cgBBDLFeS890jsJkJUGt)**

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In component declare

```
email: string = 'mailto:misesasd@gmail.com'
```

in template:

```
<a [href]="email">misesasd@gmail.com</a>
```

array:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let item of finalResults">
        <td><a [href]="item.key">{{item.key}}</a></td>
        <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
      </tr>
```

or:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of finalResults">
            <td><a href="{{item.key}}">{{item.key}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of finalResults">
    <td><a href="mailto:'item.key'">{{ item.value }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.